# Google API console missing my organization?

Tags: google-oauth, google-workspace, google-developers-console

We have a G-Suite account with our custom domain set-up and we have GMail accounts that we use normally. I am a Superadministrator in our G-suite.

In `admin.google.com` I went to billing and enabled cloud identity. It is enabled. I go to apps > other Google services and check all the services are enabled for all users for all organizations. ALL.

I navigate to `https://console.developers.google.com/getting-started` but I cannot see our organization showing up in the list of organization.

I am logged in with the same Google user, same email, same Superadmin rights.

How can I access our organization from the Google APIs portal?!

Comment: I dont think you can there two different things.   I dont think Google apis has any link to Gsuite.

Comment: I think you are right. How can I rate your answer as correct?

Comment: Wait a little while I am checking with a friend who has a bit more knowledge about gsuite then i do to be 100% sure.   He wont be up for a few more hours.